# Install Google hangout plugin for every user

Tags: installation, windows-installer, google-plus

I have conference rooms that are used for teleconferencing, but every time a new person logs into the room's computer they have to install the Google Voice and Video Chat plugin.  Also since we re-image the machine quarterly even if they do install it, it doesn't stick.

Is there a way to install the plugin so it is available to all users?

Comment: What browser?  You should be able to update the default profile to include the plugins?

Comment: When you install it from the exe it installs the plugin on FF IE and Chrome  regardless of which browser was used to download it.... I think...

Answer (score 0):

You can add a entry to the RunOnce Key to installed the plugin via batch cmd... if you need help with this lmk and i'll try to assist.  It's a poor mans fix, but it would work.